# "Error: Could not find or load main" OR "Class not found" - with android module (Gradle/IntelliJ)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have this Gradle setup:

`android/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin']
        }
    }
//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
//    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
}
```

`core/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.my.group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app-name'
include 'core'
include 'android'
```

`core/src/main/kotlin/com/my/package/Runner.kt`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("RUNS")
}
```

When I try to run the main from IntelliJ (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class RunnerKt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

BUT, when I remove this line from `settings.gradle` and refresh Gradle like this:

```
//include 'android'
```

Then the main runs.

How can I setup this project that I can run the main having an Android (library) module?

Note: I also tried running tests, then I get this error:

```
Class not found: "Tester"Empty test suite.
```

Running the tests from the command line with `./gradlew test` works in both cases. Only running things from IntelliJ wont work.

Gradle wrapper: 4.3

IntelliJ 2017.3 and 2017.2.5 tested

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KOTLIN.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, I did: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181676